# Why didn't the authors of ResNet scale their dataset by the standard deviation?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

In the original [ResNet paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf), when pre-processing their dataset, the authors subtract the mean, but they **don't** scale the images by STD (or by 255):

> The plain/residual architectures follow the form in Fig. 3 (middle/right). The network inputs are 32×32 images, **with the per-pixel mean subtracted**. The first layer is 3×3 convolutions. Then we use a stack...

Why is that? Wouldn't normalizing their dataset improve the speed of convergence if they did?

Comment: Why should dividing each data point improve the speed of convergence? All gradients etc. would simply be scaled. The numbers are not large enough to cause numerical concerns.